# Laravel: Use model to return database row based on linked table.

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use my `Website` model to get a row from my database within the `websites` table, however this row is identified through my `domains` table.

So basically it would be great to do a query on my `domains` table and match the row, then from that get the `website` row from the `websites` table using the `website_id` column.

But I want to simply pass this data into my controller by just referencing the Model within the method.

```
class WebsiteController extends Controller {

        public function index(Website $website) {

            print_r($website);

            return view('index');

        }

    }
```

My domains table:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `website_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `domain` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `active` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `website_id` (`website_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `website_id` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `websites` (`id`)
)
COMMENT='This table will contain all of the domains registered on MarvWeb, this will link to the website record. '
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

And websites table:

```
CREATE TABLE `websites` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tagline` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COMMENT='This table will contain all the websites data. '
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Add a website function to your Domain model.

```
class Domain extends Model{
    public function website(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Website');
    }
// remainder of model.
}
```

When you retrieve the Domain query results, the website can be accessed by

`print_r($domainRowResult->$website->tagline);`